# Power BI | Dax | Measure returns multiple values

Tags: powerbi, dax

Is there a way to create a DAX measure which returns multiple values at once?

Given an hypotetical table "options" and the code below, by selecting "Option 1" from a filter, for example, I would be able to get not only "_value_1" but also "_value_3". I would then like to display both values in a Matrix table as separated columns.

Table: options

| option |
| --- |
| Option 1 |
| Option 2 |
| Option 3 |

```
VAR _value_1 = "AAA"
VAR _value_2 = "BBB"
VAR _value_3 = "CCC"

RETURN
 
IF(
    HASONEVALUE(options[option]),
    SWITCH(
        VALUES(options[option]),
            "Option 1", _value_1, --> Here I would like to return also "_value_3"
            "Option 2", _value_2
        ),
    _value_1
)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

it's not clear what you mean, but if the logic is to 'pass' the relevant value to the  return statement, the code logic is nearly there: just assign the result of the switch statement to another variable then you only to pass this one. what is missing in your code is how the switch is evaluated.

another way could be to concat the results, but then you can have multiple valid results and not what you need.